# Presionar la tecla "a" y automáticamente escribir "Hola mundo" en Python?

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        pyautogui.write ('Hola mundo')
```

Aquí les dejo el código, como para hacer una idea de lo que quiero lograr. Al ejecutar el código pueden abrir algún lugar para escribir, como un (bloc de notas) y al presionar la tecla "a" una sola vez se escribirá "aHola mundo".

El problema es que cuando presionó la tecla "a" mostrará "aHola mundo".
Y no quiero que aparezca la "a" al principio, sino que solo que muestre "Hola mundo".

Básicamente es asignar una macro a una tecla.

Por favor si alguien podría ayudarme con esto!
Saludos y muchas gracias.**

Comment: Puedes insertar el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora? Es mucho más fácil de este modo que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Perdón es que soy nuevo en esto y no sabía cómo usar.

Comment: Te respondo en una respuesta.

Comment: haaa... bueno lo que quieres es escribir en un lugar y no en la consola

Comment: he editado mi respuesta ajustándolo a lo que pides

Comment: Si, quería que escribiera en cualquier lugar ya sea en bloc de notas, chat, buscador, juegos, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el módulo `keyboard` de `pynput` y `pyautogui` se puede hacer de forma muy fácil.

```py
from pynput import keyboard as kb

def accion(tecla):
    if str(tecla) == "'a'":
        pyautogui.press('backspace')
        pyautogui.write('Hello world!')
        exit() #si quieres que siempre escuche, quitalo

with kb.Listener(accion) as escuchador:
    escuchador.join()
```

Escuchamos el evento de *presionar* con `Listener()` donde le pasamos una función que será ejecutada al presionar una tecla, en este caso es la función `accion` la cual recibirá un parámetro que será la tecla presionada, luego solo comprobamos que sea la `a`. Al convertir la tecla a un string nos devuelve algo como `'a'`, ósea entre comillas, por lo que tendremos que comparar con el string `"'a'"`, las primeras comillas dobles indican que será un string y lo que dentro ya es en sí la cadena a comparar. Entonces si coincide `pyautogui` escribirá `Hello world` pero antes de eso precionará la tecla `backspace` para borrar el caracter `a`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Esto es lo que quería lograr!!

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a trabajar de una manera más sencilla? Es decir, se me ocurre que simplemente pides por teclado los datos, lo asignas a una variable y actúas en consecuencia. De este modo consigues lo que quieres:

```
while True:
opcion = input("Introduce una letra: ")
if (opcion == 'a'):
    print('Hola mundo')
```

Puedes incluso implementar un `switch-case` y discernir entre varias opciones introducidas.

Comment: El OP pide que **sólo** aparezca "Hola Mundo".

Comment: Tan sencillo como cambiar donde se pide `opcion` por `opcion = input("")`

Comment: Aun asi, igual imprime la "a". Pruebalo y veras.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer la mejor solución es usando la librería estándar `curses`

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
# Deshabilitar el eco
curses.noecho()
# Leer una tecla
option = screen.getch()

if option == ord('a'):
    print('Hola mundo')

terminar = screen.getch()
# Terminar la sesión
curses.endwin()
```

La tecla se lee con `screen.getch()`, que retorna un entero (no un caracter), por lo que tengo que hacer la comparación contra el valor numérico del caracter 'a' usando `ord(a)`.

Después de leer la tecla e imprimir el mensaje, quedamos a la espera de una segunda tecla antes de cerrar el terminal, para asi poder leer el resultado en pantalla.

Comment: Quería que escribiera automáticamente "hola mundo" en cualquier ventana para escribir. Y no que mostrará un mensaje de texto solo en la consola de Python.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia!.